# UIMA Ruta: Optional Quantifier

Tags: uima, ruta

I wanna match some terms only if the term behind this term is relevant for me. So I've created a minimal example:

This is my Test Data:

```
small Large
Large
small
```

And I wanna mark the terms **small Large** and **Large** but not "small".

So I thought, something like this should work:

```
DECLARE Test;
(SW*? CW) {-> CREATE(Test)};
```

But RUTA only matches "small Large".

For Testing I've replaced "SW" with "W" and it will do what I wan't.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, optional quantifiers at the beginning of a rule are not optional if the rule starts to match with the first rule element. This means that you either need two rules or you need to change the order of the rule element matching.

Changing the order of the rule element match lead to different rule matches since not all incremental sequences of `SW`s are considered before the `CW`. However, this is something one would normally prefer anyways. The rule would look like:

```
(SW* @CW) {-> CREATE(Test)};
```

The two rules approach would look something like:

```
(SW+? CW) {-> CREATE(Test)};
CW {-> CREATE(Test)};
```

I recommend avoiding the usage of a reluctant quantifier if it is not really required because of additional computation which are not necessary. Rather use the PARTOF condition even if it looks not as nice.

*DISCLAIMER: Iam a developer of UIMA Ruta*